# Data.gui.js clear text with confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dat.gui

[dat.gui.js](https://code.google.com/p/dat-gui/)

I am trying to use the text input in DAT.GUI.js, when I click the input box, the text input box should be clear if there has a default value. After finished, it will come out a confirm box(Message Box) to inform the user their input message.

**Right now**, My code is like this, but if I choose the `Cancel` it can not clear the input text. If the default text is not empty, I still need to delete the world use `Backspace` And also I do not want the default name "Close Controls", can I delete this?

```
var params = {
     text:""
};
var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(params, 'text').name('ID:').onFinishChange(function (value) {

        if (confirm('Is" '+ value +  ' "id?') === true) {
            workerId = value;
        } else {
            value = "";// I also tried params.text = ""; but still can not clear the input box
        }
    });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

**Solved**

```
gui.add(params, 'text').name('Your Worker ID:').listen().onFinishChange(function (value) {
    if (confirm('Is" '+ value +  ' "your worker id?') === true) {
        workerId = value;
    } else {
        params.text="";
    }
});
```

Comment: If you solved your question please post your solution as an answer rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gui.add(params, 'text').name('Your Worker ID:').listen().onFinishChange(function (value) {
    if (confirm('Is" '+ value +  ' "your worker id?') === true) {
        workerId = value;
    } else {
        params.text="";
    }
});
```